# How can I tell if didReceiveRemoteNotification is from a fetch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios7.1

I'm using the below function to detect when a remote notification is received:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"completionHandler: %@", completionHandler);
}
```

Is there a way to detect whether a notification was received from a background fetch other than checking whether the application is in the background state at the time the notification is received?

I noticed that when I log the completionHandler I get this for a non-fetched notification:

```
<__NSGlobalBlock__: (hex value)>
```

...and this for a fetched notification:

```
<__NSMallocBlock__: (hex value)>
```

Is there a way to detect the type of memory block the completionHandler is to make the differentiation between a non-fetched and fetched notification?

Thanks in advance.